# how to display random stuff without overlaping

Tags: awt

So I am creating a game in java using awt library.

I have created Meteoroid which will fall from top.

**Problem:** problem is that Meteoroid x position overlap on some of the  other meteroids.

is there math formula to do this?

```
Random r = new Random();
int maxX = WINDOW_WIDTH;
int minX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     // (x, y, width, height)
     Meteoroid m = new Meteoroid(r.nextInt(maxX - minX + 1) + minX, r.nextInt(10)+0, 40, 40);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a value for x position and increment every time a picture is created.